# Obtain all possible return values of function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Let say we have:

```
def func(a):
    if a<5:
        return "string1"
    else:
        return "string2"
```

List of possible returns of this function is `["string1","string2"]`.

Is there function in python which would return such a `list`, given `func` as an argument?

Comment: values? I guess you mean possible returns

Comment: Also, this is undecidable problem, if I'm not wrong, and for this reason it cannot be programmed.

Comment: This actually quite a tricky problem I think for more complex cases. You'd have to parse the function code yourself I guess, but a bulletproof solution will be hard, also there are potentially an infinite number of different `return` values for many functions

Comment: Do you have a `list` of all possible inputs? If so, it would be easiest to run the function on each input and store the outputs. Would work if `func()` is not expensive

Comment: I do not have list of possible inputs, but I can modify code to read off returns from list. Actually given defined classes in my program, such solution makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

No that doesn't exists ... For your function it's easy, think of a random function... The number of answers is virtually unlimited

The best you can go for is document the possible returns with docstring for instance

```
def my_function():
    """
    Do nothing, but document it.
    """
    pass

print (my_function.__doc__)
Do nothing, but document it.
```

Comment: I am aware that number of possible returns may be infinite. However, I have several functions with finite list of returns. Such list is useful for other functions and I wondered if I have to make such list manually or I can somehow automate that process.

Comment: As everyone told you above. No automatic way doing this